# reloadItemsAtIndexPath swift bug?

Tags: swift, memory, collectionview

I have some code that increases a score when you click on the relevant `UICollectionViewCell`. The code is as follows:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        teamScores[indexPath.row] += 1
        collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
}
```

This works fine initially, however when I return to the home screen and back to the app again, the app appears to freeze if I try to click on the cell again. On closer inspection, it seems like it's in some kind of loop, with the CPU running at 100% and memory required increasing every second.

Note that if instead of clicking on a cell I do another action, there are no problems as far as I can tell. The exception is a reset button, which runs the code:

```
 @IBAction func resetScores(sender: AnyObject) {
        resetScores()
        collectionView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0))
 }
```

This 'crash' only happens with the app is made active again - it does not happen when you switch to another tab and come back again.

If I replace the `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(...)` code with `reloadData()`, the problem disappears. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to deselect the cell after selecting it because it stays in a selected state.

try adding:

```
collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated : false)
```

after your:

```
teamScores[indexPath.row] += 1
```

And see if that solves your problem.

--EDIT--

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Can you add this method to the class (see edit of original post)

Comment: No luck with that either!